# Represent an enum as a String in java Swagger

Tags: java, spring, swagger, springfox

I have this object in java with an attribute called type, that represents an enum:

```
public class Patch<T> {
   @JsonProperty("path")
   protected String path;
   @JsonProperty("op")
   protected TypeValue op;
   @JsonProperty("value")
   protected T value;
}
```

This object, when generating a spec in yaml using springfox generates this output when referencing the object TypeValue:

```
 Patch:
type: object
properties:
  op:
    type: string
    enum:
    - add
    - remove
    - replace
    - move
    - copy
  path:
    type: string
  value:
    type: object
    properties: {}
title: Patch
```

What I want to do is to ignore the enum type when generating the doc, removing the **enum** type from the spec. Tis is what I want:

```
Patch:
```

type: object
properties:
op:
type: string
path:
type: string
value:
type: object
properties: {}
title: Patch

I tried to use the     @ApiModelProperty(dataType = "string", allowValues = "A, B, C") but the result is the same

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using `@Hidden` ?

https://docs.swagger.io/swagger-core/v2.1.1/apidocs/io/swagger/v3/oas/annotations/Hidden.html